# If I store the output of nested for loop only the last elements of the loop are printed, but print function prints all the combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

```
l1 = ['a','b']
l2 = ['c','d']
for x in l1:
   for y in l2:
       (a,b)=(x,y)
```

When I `print(a,b)`, all I get is `('b','d')`, but when I enter the code like

```
for x in l1:
   for y in l2:
       print((x,y))
```

all possible combinations of `l1` and `l2` are printed. Why is this happening and how do I go about this?

Comment: You printed `(a,b)` outside loops.

Comment: How many times does a and b change between your calls to print? Now how many times do x and y change between calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give you all possible combinations

```
l1 = ['a','b']
l2 = ['c','d']

for x in l1:
   for y in l2:
       (a, b) = (x, y)
       print(a, b)
```

Also, take a look at the alternative solution

```
from itertools import product


l1 = ['a','b']
l2 = ['c','d']

for (a, b) in product(l1, l2):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: The question asks why is it happening, the op already has a working solution

Comment: @Sayse since his solution doesn't print all possible combinations it doesn't work, but my does. The answer to the question appears after comparing the non-working solution and the working one.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `(a,b)=(x,y)` it sets the value of `a` equal to the value of `x` and `b` equal to the value of `y`. Everytime you run through the for loop `a` and `b` get over ridden. The `print` statement on the other hand just writes to stdout whatever the value of those two variables is at the time. If you want to store those values for use after the for loop I would recommend appending them to a list.

```py
l1 = ['a','b']
l2 = ['c','d']

combinations = []
for x in l1:
   for y in l2:
       combinations.append((x, y))
```

Or as in Roman Dryndik's answer you could use the `product` function.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that when you do

```
l1 = ['a','b']
l2 = ['c','d']
for x in l1:
   for y in l2:
       (a,b)=(x,y)
```

I assume you are calling the print function outside the for loop (you didn't show where you called it in your pasted code). In your code, the values of a and b are reassigned during each iteration, so when you call it after the for loop it will just print what a and b were last assigned to.

And when you did:

```
l1 = ['a','b']
l2 = ['c','d']

for (a, b) in product(l1, l2):
    print(a, b)
```

You called the print function inside the for loop. This means it is reached during every iteration, so it makes sense that it will print the values of a and b during each iteration.